# Can't install windows 10 on GPT in UEFI mode. What am I missing?

Tags: windows-10, installation, uefi, windows-installation, gpt

It says **We couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one**
What am I missing really? I create a bootable usb with rufus with GPT/UEFI target. I boot my system in UEFI after selecting booting from UEFI USB. I've got a 4 tb drive in GPT already. Nope. Get this warning.

Comment: Did you try making a bootable Windows 10 ISO from the Microsoft Media Creation link?

Comment: @John nope. Why? You think it's rufus's fault here? I should try another tool?

Comment: Just try the Windows 10 ISO to install. That should work. You can make it bootable from the Microsoft site.

Comment: As @John points out.. use the media creation tool, use the windows 10 ISO.  Yes, it's rufus' fault.  Great tool.. don't use it for windows.  No need.